# How do you create code references with custom link text in documentation comments?

Tags: c#, documentation-generation, xml-documentation, docfx

I am porting an application library from Java to C#. In the Java documentation, there are places that link to a particular code reference using custom text. For example:

```
Suffix --&gt; {@link DataOutput#writeString String}
```

I tried using a similar approach in XML documentation comments...

```
Suffix --&gt; <see cref="DataOutput.WriteString(string)">String</see>
```

... but the whole link just vanishes from both Intellisense and the generated documentation when I try it that way. The question is, how do I construct similar code links with custom text using .NET XML documentation comments in C#? If there is no way to do it, what is the recommended workaround?

If it matters, we are experimenting with using the [DocFx](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/) code generator.

Comment: Have a look at SandCastle which is able to produce HTML-helpfiles (aside some others also) from your xml-docs. However VS isn´t able to handle links to other types or members as eclipse does for instance.

Comment: DocFX supports such comments to generate a link. It's also used in its source code like [this](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/blob/1a191f6f1853e48873d5f45003cda669d3df0cca/src/Microsoft.DocAsCode.Dfm/IDfmEngineCustomizer.cs#L11). Is the referenced method also built by DocFX?

Comment: @Yuby - The link you referenced has a *standard code link* that uses the name of the code element as the link text (in this case `DfmEngineBuilder`). What I am asking about is making the link text into something other than the name of the code element that is referenced, such  as `My Custom Text` (since it was done that way in the code that is being ported).

Comment: Now I get your point. I'm afraid the <see> tag doesn't support it. You need to use DocFX's [cross reference](http://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/links_and_cross_references.html#different-syntax-of-cross-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DocFX's cross reference syntax: `[String](xref:DataOutput.WriteString(System.String))`.

See: http://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/links_and_cross_references.html#different-syntax-of-cross-reference

Comment: or alternatively: `@"DataOutput.WriteString(System.String)?text=string"`